# SSLHandshakeException - PKIX - After migrate Glassfish 2 to 5

Tags: java-8, migration, glassfish, glassfish-5

I've got an application that was running on Glassfish 2.1. After a migration to use Glassfish 5.1 i'm facing a problem. Everytime that my application is making any request to an external API or Amazon SQS, for example, i'm getting the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Before the migration, all the requests was working successfully.

I've already tried to set this propreties:

> System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "false");
> System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","clientTrustStore.key");
> System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","qwerty");

And added into the domain.xml

> <jvm-options>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</jvm-options>

And also, i've already tried to create a custom class implementing `X509TrustManager`

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Already try all the solutions above and the error still the same.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/24523

Answer (score 0):

This is because you call the external API via HTTPS a GlassFish only allows such connections if the external services presents a cerrtificate that GlassFish can trust.

GlassFish only trusts certificates that are in the trust store file `cacerts.jks` in the GlassFish domain. It's possible that GlassFish 2 didn't have this requirement and it allowed connections to any external service.

There's a discussion about this on the GlassFish issue tracker: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/24523#issuecomment-1657651280

A solution is to download the certificate presented by the external API and install it into the `cacerts.jks` file, which is in `config` directory of GlassFish domain. You can use the keytool command line tool available in the JDK.

Alternatively, you can import all certificates from your JDK into the `cacerts.jks` file. It's likely that it's enough if the external services present certificates isgned by trusted public authorities.